# Sketch $\text{Arg}( 1 - z ) = \pi/2$ and find the Cartesian equation

Tags: geometry

This is a question I was thinking about when doing Edexcel FP2, seen something like it before but not sure where. Tried to solve it but cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\arg(1-z)=\frac\pi2$, it follows that
$$
z=z-1+1=1-(1-z)=1-\alpha e^{i\frac\pi2}=1-i\alpha,
$$
with $\alpha>0$, i.e. $x=1$, with $y<0$.

Comment: Hey Mercy thanks for answering, I see that you manipulated the complex number Z. How can I use what you have done to sketch the graph?

Comment: Also, can  manipulate this function the following way :         arg ( 1 - z) = pi/2,    arg (-1(z-1)) = pi/2 , arg (-1) + arg (z-1) = pi/2.   If not why?